# Syslog forwared HAProxy logs filtering in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

I'm having issues understanding how to do this correctly.

I have the following Logstash config:

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/star_server_com.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/server.key"
    type => "somelogs"
 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    host => "es01.server.com"
  }
}
```

With logstash-forwarder, I'm pushing my haproxy.log file generated by syslog to logstash. Kibana then shows me a `_source` which looks like this:

```
{"message":"Dec 8 11:32:20 localhost haproxy[5543]: 217.116.219.53:47746 [08/Dec/2014:11:32:20.938] es_proxy es_proxy/es02.server.com 0/0/1/18/20 200 305 - - ---- 1/1/1/0/0 0/0 \"GET /_cluster/health HTTP/1.1\"","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-12-08T11:32:21.603Z","type":"syslog","file":"/var/log/haproxy.log","host":"haproxy.server.com","offset":"4728006"}
```

Now, this has to be filtered (somehow) and I have to admit I haven't got the slightest idea how.
Looking at [the grok documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) and fiddling with the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) I still haven't got anything useful out of Logstash and Kibana.

I've been scanning the patterns directory and their files, and I can't say I understand how to use them. I was hoping that providing a filter with a haproxy pattern Logstash would match the pattern from my `_source` but that was without any luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're in luck since there already is a predefined grok pattern that appears to parse this exact type of log. All you have to do is refer to it in a [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok):

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{HAPROXYHTTP}"]
  }
}
```

`%{HAPROXYHTTP}` will be recursively expanded according to the [pattern definition](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/haproxy) and each interesting piece in every line of input will be extracted to its own field. You may also want to remove the 'message' field after a successful application of the grok filter since it contains redundant data anyway; just add `remove_field => ["message"]` to the grok filter declaration.